# Copy batch files to Jenkins Slaves with Different OS versions

Tags: jenkins, plugins, jenkins-agent

I am running automated tests of our application on different versions of an OS build (Windows 7, Windows 10, etc...).  My testing suite requires that I copy files to the Slave computers when there are changes in the tests (external to the build application). The test files are not in the Jenkins work space as they do not change frequently and therefore do not need to be copied to the Slave with each execution.

I am looking to be able to update the files on the Slaves, but not under the work space directory, so the Copy-To-Slave plugin will not work from my understanding.

I am looking to have batch files, testing resource files, DB generation scripts and others copied to the Slave computer by a Jenkins job.  This job may monitor GIT, but not everything being copied is from git.

In essence, execute the following but to the Slave computer

xcopy C:\Testing*.* C:\Resources\Testing /s/v/e

The reason for this is our testing scripts look for certain files to execute (DB scripts for building the database for the current platform/DB Engine) and as these do not change too frequently, we only need to copy the files when they are changed, and leave the files in place for subsequent test runs.  There is a large amount of files and GBs of data that does not need to be copied with each test run. There are also multiple executions of the application with the same testing files where the application has different configurations, but should produce the same results, so the test files do not need to be copied with each of these executions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a configuration on the Copy-To-Slave plugin to add additional directories as destinations, that are relative to the file system root directory (C:\ in my case) which will solve my problem.

[image: Define an additional 'Paths are relative to' option]